# SQL Server 2008 R2 hamachi connection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to connect to remote DB over Hamachi, the tutorial states that I need to set tcp/ip to enable (which I did, in SQL Server Configuration Management tool) and add Hamachi IP to ipadresses, but which one? ip4,ip6...

Comment: I think this is off-topic here and should be asked on Super User or Server Fault as the issue is basically how to configure Hamachi.

Comment: Well, I intented to post there also...And my question is about MS sql configuration menager tool

Comment: `add Hamachi IP to ipadresses, but which one` you have to configure Hamachi to connect to SQL server and not the other way around.